# How do I match against multiple conditions on a table join?

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
users          attributes
id|name        id|name|user_id
-------        ---------------
1 |foo         1 |bla | 1
2 |bar         1 |blub| 1
               1 |bla | 2
```

How do I create a query gives users with both the "bla" AND "blub" attributes?

In this case it should only return the user "foo".

I know that the data is not normalized.

Comment: I've made an edit to your question & title, in hopes that it will be a bit clearer.  Feel free to revert if you don't feel I've improved your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT u.*, a.id, b.Id, a.name, b.name  FROM users u
JOIN attributes a
ON a.User_id = u.User_id AND a.name = 'bla'
JOIN attributes b
ON u.User_Id = b.User_id AND b.name = 'blub'
```

Comment: I think `u.name` should be `a.name` and `b.name`.

Comment: And I'd wrap the value, e.g.: `'bla'`. However, +1 for the right answer.

Comment: Y'see, these are the reasons I use developer tools that catch the stupid mistakes - I typo too much and forget things like quotes when I'm rushing.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't matter. The basic idea was right from the first revision, the rest relies on the OP. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an attribute association to a user is unique...

if you need 3 conditions to be true add the conditions to the in and adjust count  up 1.

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN attributes a on A.user_Id = u.id
WHERE a.name in ('bla','blub')
GROUP by u.name
HAVING count(*)=2
```

and if you don't have an unique association, or you need to join to another table you could always do...

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN attributes a on A.user_Id = u.id
WHERE a.name in ('bla','blub')
GROUP by u.name
HAVING count(distinct A.name)=2
```

for a slight performance hit.  but this allows you to join and get back additional fields which others have indicated was a detriment to this method.

This allows for scaling of the solution instead of incurring the cost of joining each time to different tables. In addition, if you needed thirty-something values to associate, you may run into restrictions on the number of allowed joins.

Comment: This works, I suppose, though if he needed more than users.name or users.user_id as output it wouldn't work terribly well.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  U.NAME
FROM    USERS U
INNER JOIN
        ATTRIBUTES A1
ON      U.ID = A1.USER_ID
INNER JOIN
        ATTRIBUTES A2
ON      U.ID = A2.USER_ID
WHERE   A1.NAME = 'bla'
AND     A2.NAME = 'blub'
```

Comment: This works, but I have found that it seems to go faster when you put the conditions on the `on` statement - I believe it may prune the tables before the join when you do that.  Whether I'm right or not, it seems faster to me (though I don't have anything but subjective analysis to back that up).

Comment: @Jeff, I agree. When I run these types of queries, I always make this part of the `JOIN` clause. I wrote it this way as I was favoring easy of understanding over performance.

Comment: To @Declan's point, it is worth noting that it could be preferable from a maintainability standpoint to keep it in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the INTERSECT operator

```
SELECT 
   u.id
  ,u.name
  FROM users AS u
  INNER JOIN attributes AS a
    ON u.id = a.user_id
  WHERE a.name = 'bla'

INTERSECT

SELECT 
   u.id
  ,u.name
  FROM users AS u
  INNER JOIN attributes AS a
    ON u.id = a.user_id
  WHERE a.name = 'blub'
;
```

Here is a demo on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68986/5

More info on SET operations in SQL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)

Comment: I haven't used the INTERSECT (or any SET operations) before, but it looks as if it works.  It's certainly readable to anyone familiar with sets.  How does the performance compare with the multiple-join method?

Comment: It would depend on a lot of different factors.  Here is a blog post that looks at performance: http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/t-sql-set-operators-intersect-except-and-union/

I would recommend comparing the execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.name  
FROM attributes a 
JOIN users u   
   ON u.id = a.user_id 
WHERE a.name IN ('bla','bulb')
```

Comment: This will never work - a.name cannot be 'bla' AND 'bulb' simultaneously, you're doing a non-wildcard match against the same field with different strings.

Comment: The current revision did not change too much I'm afraid. ;-)

Comment: Putting the cases in an `in` statement doesn't help, either.  It roughly equates to doing an `OR` on them.  The only way I'm aware of to test for both attributes (outside of 2 joins) is xQbert's method.  It looks like it should work, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Oh my goodness. It must be too early for me. You are absolutely and entirely correct. I am glad we had this conversation.